# How to get User id by username in Facebook Graph API v2.1

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

we are developing a web app and were getting the user ids by using the username via FQL. Unfortunately, Graph API v2.1 does not support FQL anymore. I haven't found a way how to reference the username to find the user id in the documentation.

Is there a solution? Or is that not possible with the Graph API. I know that I can query the user ID using the name, but with the username, it would be better in our scenario.

Comment: You can't. Facebook specifically doesn't want you to be able to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This is intentional for privacy reasons. If you would be able to get the (real) User ID with the unique username, there would be no need to invent App Scoped ID at all.

If you make a call to `/me/username`, it will return the following error:

> (#803) Cannot query users by their username

Btw, you cannot even get the username since v2.0, only the real name.

Comment: I did not find where in the question "the real user id" is mentioned? It was possible to get the user id via the graph API and username before but it is not possible in v2.x. It does not matter that for the new users the user id is app scoped - it is still not possible to get it via the API by username. There is no logical reason why this is not possible.

Comment: >If you would be able to get the (real) User ID with the unique username, there would be no need to invent App Scoped ID at all. - nonsense! Both are unique, one is just a nicer human readable version of the other.

Comment: they are unique indeed, but the username and the real id would allow developers to identify the user even when he removed access to the app. not sure if you got my point, but i will repeat it: app scoped users were invented to protect the privacy of users.