# Facebook API Graph. Instagram. How to get user profile picture knowing only username?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm implementing webhook subscription to receive notifications about new comments on Instagram media (so, the solution assumes server side environment).
Webhook payload contains a comment ID. Fetching a comment node via Facebbok API Graph call I can get author's username.
From this point I need to get author's profile picture.

Currently I can use Business Discovery API to get information about user by username like this

```
GET graph.facebook.com/%PAGEID%
    ?fields=business_discovery.username(%USERNAME%){...fields...}
```

But this method is working only for Instagram Business accounts.

Recently, this task can be accomplished with `https://www.instagram.com/%USERNAME%/?__a=1` call, but now this request requires authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the user profile picture by using the username, because facebook denies querying users by their username:

```
(#803) Cannot query users by their username
```

Even if, [indeed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/), getting the facebook picture of a user does not require an access token or any permissions.

You need to get the userid (`10000xxxxxxxxxx`), and then you'd be able to:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{userid}/picture
```

Comment: So, now the question is "Is it possible to get userid by instagram username" )

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of the restriction. There are multiple topics on that, here is one of them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306754/how-to-get-user-id-by-username-in-facebook-graph-api-v2-1

Comment: This endpoint appears to require authorization and my Instagram Basic Display token returns an `Invalid OAuth access token`, `190` response. Can you provide more context for your solution?

Comment: @LukePighetti i just retried and it works the same way, no authorization required with a GET req over an id of this format `10000xxxxxxxxxx`.

Comment: Does this work with a normal instagram userid? I've got it here in postman failing every time.

Comment: `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/15239448540/picture`. `"message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",`